# Ionic2/Angular2: Source navigational methods from components out to central service

Tags: angular, ionic2

This is in every single of our components:

```
import { HomePage } from '../../home/home';
@Component({
..
    dismiss() {
       this.navController.setRoot(HomePage)
    }
```

How to do this from inside a service? (we tried and it does not work, see: [Angular2: Pass Component Page from Service to other Component does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310484/angular2-pass-component-page-from-service-to-other-component-does-not-work))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can se [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-cant-i-import-navcontroller-and-viewcontroller-into-service-or-app/40999/26), @mhartington (from ionic team) says:

> Just to chime in on this, you shouldn't be injecting ViewController or
>   NavController into Service. This is not their intended purpose.

And

> The service shouldn't be responsible for displaying alerts/loading/ or
>   any component that needs to be activated by nav. A service should just
>   be for getting and returning data.
>
> Anything else should be done within the component.

That being said, you can obtain the `NavController` by doing

```
var nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
```

Like you can see [here](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/ionic-2-ui-alert-from-a-angular-2-service-221a2e526760#.p1wdqd564).

=================================================

**EDIT:** As another user said:

> It's bad practice to change a view from a service (broken MVC).
>   However, you could send events from services to the main controller,
>   and the controller can use NavController (best way), or you could send
>   NavController to your service like an attribute (not bad way...). Or
>   you may need to create a component instead of using the service.

So, a better way to do it, would be:

First, add an `observable` in your service, to know when the `dismiss` should be called:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyCustomService {

  // Observables we're going to use
  private dismissObserver: any;
  public dismiss: any;

  constructor(private platform: Platform){
    // Your stuff
    // ...

    this.dismissObserver = null;
    this.dismiss = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.dismissObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  public yourMethod(...):void {
    // Here we send the order to go back to the home page
    this.dismissObserver.next(true);
  }
}
```

And then **only**, in your `app.ts` (or in your top-most component):

```
 initializeApp(): void {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

      // We subscribe to the dismiss observable of the service
      this.myCustomService.dismiss.subscribe((value) => {
        this.navController.setRoot(HomePage);
      });
    });
  }
```

Remember to add it in the `ionicBootstrap` of your app:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [MyCustomService, ...], {
  //statusbarPadding: true
});
```

Or, following the [Angular2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#07-03), add it as a `provider` in the top-most component (MyApp in this case):

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  directives: [...],
  providers: [MyCustomService]
})
class MyApp {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thabk you for this detailed and perfect answer.

Comment: One question though regarding MVVC: If Service is not part of controller, is it part of what exactly?